# Practical Use for 4D+ Arrays

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I have been studying Java and C++ this year, and I am wondering; what practical uses are there for a 4 or even 5 dimensional array? My teacher basically says that you are using the wrong datatype if you want to use a 4 dimensional array.

Have you ever used a 4 of 5 (or more) dimensional array? What did you use it for? What practical uses can you think of for them?

Thanks!

Comment: n-Sided Rubik's Cube program

Comment: @Tdorno really?  You use 4 dimensions to simulate n sides?

Comment: @DavidWallace I don't see why you couldn't.

Comment: Please see `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5540024/java-program-using-4d-array`

Comment: There are lots of models in Math and Physics with 4D or more Matrix, a good programming language should be able to model them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A practical use of a 4D array is to keep track of a 3d object, could keep track of [x-cord][y-cord][z-cord][time]. This 4D array would be a useful use of a 4D array. This could keep track of a range of cords and time, and the value in the array could say the speed of of the object.

```
Speed = arr[5][9][6][1500];
```

That would record the speed of the object when it was at x cord 5, y cord 9, z cord 6, and say been alive for 1500 seconds.

As for your 5D array:

```
int left; //#of cars left in world
left = allCars[year][brand][color][condition][horsepower];
```

brand count be an int(have a table of values aka Ferrari = 1, same with color. Condition could be on a scale of 0 being destroyed, to 1 being brand new).

Then you could find the # of 1947 Ferrari's that are red in brand new condition with 200 horsepower.

Aka in general you could use many dimensional arrays to keep track of large databases of things.

Answer (score 1):

You may create a **[Sodoku hypercube with 4 dimensions](http://casa.colorado.edu/~ajsh/sr/hypercube.html)** and then you can store the number which the user enters into a 4dimensional int array.

> Rotating 4D hypercube (GIF movie). Imagine a person who lives in 4
>   spatial dimensions, watching a hypercube rotate. The 4-dimensional
>   person has a 3-dimensional retina in each of its 2 eyes (two eyes
>   suffice for depth perception, even in 4D). Each retina records a
>   3-dimensional image.
>
> This image shows what the 4-dimensional person sees, with the extra
>   dimension shown as a variation in colour. That is, the horizontal,
>   vertical, and `colour' directions correspond to the 3 directions on
>   the 3-dimensional retina of the 4-dimensional person. The vertical bar
>   to the right of the picture shows the correspondence between colour
>   and position in the extra dimension.

Also you may check the **[Tesseract](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesseract)**

Answer (score 1):

Take almost anything from physics, where tensors are common, for example general relativity, computational chemistry, quantum physics.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor#Applications

Tensor with rank 4 is common for example.

http://www.oonumerics.org/FTensor/FTensor.pdf

http://mpqc.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/mpqc/trunk/mpqc/src/lib/chemistry/qc/lmp2/lmp2.cc?revision=9342&view=markup&pathrev=9492

Answer (score 1):

The example was a stock-keeping system where jeans could be indexed by

```
 inventory[size][length][color][fit] = number_received
```

which is only slightly contrived. You'd have no problem with a database structured in such a way but it does look funny as code.

Comment: What type of the inventory be? String? int? Just out of curiosity.

Comment: @Lain Obviously the thing will be int in a stock keeping system. Which is to make an eye on the counts and when it come to lower bound they will order again...

Answer (score 0):

You might be running a geophysics simulation, where you have a 3D region such as an oil field, and you are measuring the relative quantities of different substances found at different points in the region (oil, water, sand, porous rock and so on).  You might have three dimensions for the position, and one dimension for which substance you're looking at.